# Run OWASP Dependency Check on all old versions

Tags: maven, owasp, owasp-dependency-check

The normal OWASP Dependency Check Maven plug-in makes a good job of scanning the current version of a project for vulnerabilities in its dependencies.

But how about vulnerabilities that are reported for the dependencies of old versions of the project?

All guides to OWASP Dependency Check I have seen describe how to set it up to check only the current version of a project.

I believe that to be avoid vulnerabilities all versions of a project that are still in use should be checked regularly, both current and old. The check should also run periodically, not just when a build is performed.

**What is the best way to use OWASP Dependency Check to do this?**

One way would be to check all artifacts that are deployed to a certain Maven repository. Is there any good ways to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have a tag or branch in your source repository for each old version of the software, so you have to checkout this tag/branch in your workspace before running the dependency check.  This operation can be automated by some continuos integration tool like Jenkins.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely one reasonable solution! The solution we used was to create a script that downloads all pom-files that we have deployed to our internal Maven repo, using the GitLab API. The script then runs a Maven build with just the pom files. I think our solution has both advantages and disadvantages compared to what you propose.